# How to test queries with Entity Framework Core and Linq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, nunit

I have my .NET Core solution structured with clean architecture. In the persistence project I have my repositories. In the implementation I have some calls to the database with Linq.

```
public class QualitativeResearchRepository 
       : BaseRepository<QualitativeResearch>, IQualitativeResearchRepository
{
    public QualitativeResearchRepository(PSCContext db,
           ILogger<QualitativeResearchRepository> log) 
           : base(db, log)
    {
    }

    public decimal GetAverageForClarity(
          Expression<Func<QualitativeResearch, bool>> func)
    {
        var list = _db.QualitativeResearches.Select(r => r.Clarity)
                      .DefaultIfEmpty();

        if (list == null || list.Count() == 0)
            return 0;

        var result = list.Average();

        return result == null ? 0 : (decimal)result;
    }
}
```

So, there are functions where I want to apply filters and/or aggregations and then some calculations. I want to mock the context (in the code `PSCContext`) so I can test if the filters and aggregation are correct as I expect. On the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking?redirectedfrom=MSDN) there are examples but only for add new record.

Comment: Just to confirm - this is EF _Core_, correct? You've tagged this EF Core but the documentation you linked is for EF 6 (.NET Framework).

Comment: yes, it is EF Core. The MSDocsis for .NET Framework but the `Mock` part could be the same.

Comment: The InMemory provider?

Comment: check the docs regarding different approaches like `inmemory` or `sqllite` mock
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Entity Framework Core, Microsoft recommends using an in-memory provider for unit testing. It's just as quick at runtime and a lot less complex than trying to unravel the internals of EF's DbContext. For more information on why this is bad, [see their explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/testing/#unit-testing).

> We use test doubles for internal testing of EF Core. However, we never try to mock DbContext or IQueryable. Doing so is difficult, cumbersome, and fragile. **Don't do it.**

For starters, you'll want to install the EF Core In Memory provider.

> dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory

From there, you can simply construct your DbContext, using the `DbContextOptions<T>` constructor.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory

// Further down...

public void GivenAnyFilter_WhenNoRecordsAreFound_ThenReturnsZero()
{
    var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PSCContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDatabase")
        .Options;

    var dbContext = new PSCContext(dbContextOptions);

    // Setup your test and invoke...
}
```

Comment: In `.UseInMemoryDatabase()` you have to specified a database name. So, the line is `var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PSCContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase("FakeDb").Options;`. Thank you

Comment: Edited! Sorry was doing it off the top of my head.

Comment: Well, in fact they don't recommend the in-memory provider for testing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli.

Comment: Of course - integration testing it's going to fall flat. However, in a unit test context it is perfect as the database itself is not a concern. This is what OP is trying to test. From the link above -> "None of this is very important when testing EF Core internals because we use it specifically where the database is irrelevant to the test."

Comment: How is database not a concern when the question is *"How to test **queries** with Entity Framework Core and Linq?"* What exact queries are you testing with in-memory provider - LINQ to Objects? Many things in query processing pipeline are different, hence the test is useless. And don' rely so much on official links, in fact they (EFC teams) are considering retiring the in-memory provider. [SQLite in-memory database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sqlite#using-sqlite-in-memory-databases) is better, but still is different from the real database (like SqlServer etc.)

Comment: From the question -> " I want to mock the context... so I can test if the filters and aggregation are correct..." are not database concerns - those are business concerns.

Comment: @BenSampica There are so many differences between LINQ to objects and LINQ to a SQL backend that inevitably lots of filters will behave differently. Look at this tricky `func` parameter of which OP probably forgot to show how it's used. It's more than likely that predicates will be entered that succeed in memory but not in SQL translation. Or the reverse, which is just as bad.